# How do I implement a switch statement in Uniface 10.4?

Tags: uniface

I want to implement a switch statement in Uniface, as is possible in C# and Java.

Does this functionality exist in Uniface 10.4 and if so, how do I implement it?

My IF-ELSE statement looks like this:

```
if (value = 100) 
    return 1
elseif (value = 200)
    return 2
elseif (value = 300)
    return 3
else
    return -1
endif
```